# Button Bar to alter url source of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a button bar that changes an attr of a defined object but cannot get it to work. See below code snippets (CSS Not included):

Button Bar Code

```
<ul id="filtering-nav">
<li class="work button active" value="../servlet/Web">Work</li>
<li class="like button"  value="../servlet/Home">home</li></ul>
```

Script Code

```
<script> var buttons = $("#filtering-nav .button"); buttons.click(function(){
buttons.removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
$( "#alpha100" ).attr("data", $("#filtering-nav .button.selected").val() );});</script>
```

Target Object Code

```
<object id='alpha100' type="text/html" data=""  width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

I can get something similar to work with a drop down box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `.button.active` instead of `.button.selected`.

But you can make your code simpler :

```
var buttons = $("#filtering-nav .button");
buttons.click(function(){
   buttons.removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
   $("#alpha100" ).attr("data", $(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Note that today custom attributes should be named `data-something`. `data` and `value` aren't good attribute names. Using standard custom data attributes, you'd use the specific [data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function :

```
   $("#alpha100" ).data("something", $(this).data('otherthing'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is happening behind the scenes when you try to use `value` for a `li` tag. That might be part of the problem so I suggest you this approach (using `data` attribute)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="filtering-nav">
   <li class="work button active" data-value="../servlet/Web">Work</li>
   <li class="like button"  data-value="../servlet/Home">home</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
<script> 
    var buttons = $("#filtering-nav .button"); buttons.click(function(){
    buttons.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $( "#alpha100" ).attr("data", $("#filtering-nav .button.selected").data('value') );});
</script>
```

Something else (as dystroy pointed out): did you mean `.button.active` instead of `.button.selected`?